# Don't show hidden triangles in Object Mode

Tags: 3d-view, object-mode

In Edit Mode, I've hidden some triangles. But when I switch back to Object Mode, the entire mesh is rendered. Is there a way to not render hidden triangles when in Object Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the vertices to a [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html) and then use a [mask modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/mask.html) to hide the vertices.

By adjusting the [visibility settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html#interface) of the modifier you can also use it to hide the vertices in edit mode or only hide them when rendering.

[image]